# Apache and SSL Issues

Tags: apache2, ssl

I have my server set up to use SSL in a separate VirtualHost, but when I attempt to use https://my.domain, I get a connection refused error. The following is my config I'm using:

```
<VirtualHost 173.0.50.62:80>
    ServerName api.bb0.us
    DocumentRoot /home/tristan/bb0_www/api
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 173.0.50.62:443>
    ServerName api.bb0.us
    DocumentRoot /home/tristan/bb0_www/api
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/bb0_cert/bb0.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/bb0_cert/private.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/bb0_cert/root.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

If you do try to go to http://bb0.us everything will work, but when you attempt https://bb0.us, it will not work. I don't have ufw or anything else blocking this, so I'm confused why this is not working. I've tried to add a NameVirtualHost, but that didn't do anything in fixing this.

Anyone have any ideas what may be causing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you enabled Apache's SSL module?  If not, running the following commands should do the trick:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If `mod_ssl` is not loaded, then Apache won't listen on port 443 by default or SSL connections.

Comment: Unbelievable. Wasted about an hour trying to figure this out just because none of the "top results" said to `a2enmod ssl`.