# SSL on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I cant figure out how to activate ssl on apache2 in ubuntu server 14.04 `?
on my ubuntu server i have installed

1. lamp
2. owncloud

i havent made any configuration on the lamp server yet. only isntalled owncloud so i can acces it on my wan ip.

i have tried followin a guide from digital ocean but i am getting this message after service apache2 restart

root@Owncloud:/home/daniel# sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

- router ip - 192.168.1.1
- host machine´s ip 192.168.1.109
- wan ip 82.180.xx.xxx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache error "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have port 443 open on my router. I opened it, and now it works.

Thanks for all of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Although technically this is not a question, the warning you get is a *warning*. Also using `sudo` is not required when you are root. Lastly, if you want ssl on your apache server, you should [configure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52110/apache-and-ssl-issues) it.

Comment: i have been following this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04